# What is the point of having metric mapping modes like MM_LOMETRIC, and MM_LOENGLISH?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi

Page number 47 of book **Programming with MFC** **(second edition)** by Jeff Prosise (chapter 2: Drawing in a window), has the following statement.

> One thing to keep in mind when you use the metric mapping modes is that on display screens, 1 logical inch usually doesn't equal 1 physical inch. In other words, if you draw a line that's 100 units long in the MM_LOENGLISH mapping mode, the line probably won't be exactly 1 inch long.

My question is, if windows cannot give any guarantee on the physical dimensions of things we draw using metric mapping modes, then what is the point of having such a mapping mode? Are metric mapping modes relevant only for printers, and completely irrelevant for monitors?

In modern monitors, with digital ports like HDMI/Display port, can't windows OS get physical dimensions of the screen, thus making it possible to draw things using metric dimensions (inches, rather than pixels, note that the current resolution of the monitor will already be known to the OS)?

Comment: They are *primarily* relevant for non-display output devices, including printers, plotters, etc. However, they *can* be useful for monitors. MFC uses it to implement things like Print Preview. Yes, with modern monitors Windows could do certain things a bit more nicely, perhaps, but since the time machine has not yet been developed, they can't go back and change the semantics of the GDI subsystem, developed some 20+ years ago.

Comment: Video drivers have had a very long history of fibbing about the monitor resolution.  Starting with them just not having any idea whatsoever because the electrical interconnection with the monitor was not good enough.  Got locked into 96 dpi, that got very hard to change because just about every programmer assumed it was the default and did not bother writing the scaling code.  That's been changing btw, this just can't work anymore with 4k monitors getting common and DPI-virtualization turning too ugly.  Win10 in particular no longer uses that default, lots and lots of questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas behind the logical inch is that viewing distance to a monitor was typically larger than the distance to a printed page, so it made sense to have the default of a logical inch on a typical monitor be a bit larger than a physical inch, especially in an era where WYSIWYG was taking off.  Rather than put all of the burden to adjust for device resolution on the application, the logical inch lets WYSIWYG application developer think in terms of distances and sizes on the printed page and not have to work in pixels or dots which varied widely from device to device (and especially from monitor to printer).

Another issue was that, with the relatively limited resolutions of early monitors, it just wasn't practical to show legible text as small as typically printed text.  For example, text was commonly printed at 6 lines per inch.  At typical monitor resolutions, this might mean 12 pixels per line, which really limits font design and legibility (especially before anti-aliased and sub-pixel rendered text was practical).  Making the logical inch default to 120-130% of an actual inch (on a typical monitor of the era) means lines of text would be 16 pixels high, making typographic niceties like serifs and italic more tenable (though still not pretty).

Also keep in mind that the user controls the logical inch and could very well set the logical inch so that it matches the physical inch if that suited their needs.

The logical units are still useful today, even as monitors have resolutions approaching those of older laser printers.  Consider designing slides for a presentation that will be projected and also printed as handouts.  The projection size is a function of the projector's optics and its distance from the screen.  There's no way, even with two-way communication between the OS and the display device for the OS to determine the actual physical size (nor would it be useful for most applications).

I'm not a CSS expert, but it's my understanding that even when working in CSS's `px` units, you're working in a logical unit that may not be exactly the size of a physical pixel.  It's supposed to take into account the actual resolution of the device and the typical viewing distance, allowing web designers to make the same 96-per-inch assumption that native application developers had long been using.